# Debug CGI by simulation

Tags: c++, apache, cgi, environment-variables

I basically want to debug a cgi programm with gdb by emulating the environment variables and stdin stream.
How do I set the variables and stdin?

I am using lampp and gdb.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://inside.mines.edu/~lwiencke/elab/gdb/gdb_19.html:

```
show environment [varname]
set environment varname [=] value
```

And from http://davis.lbl.gov/Manuals/GDB/gdb_5.html#SEC22

> You can redirect your program's input
>   and/or output using shell redirection
>   with the run command. For example,

E.g.

```
run < input_file
```

would redirect the standard input of your debugged program.